# What did John of Salisbury write about the concepts of "logical depth and breadth"?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, history-of-philosophy

In the Digital companion to Peirce [site](http://www.commens.org/dictionary/term/logical-depth) there is the following text about the logical depth and breadth:

> …it was between six and seven centuries ago that John of Salisbury
> spoke of it as “fere in omnium ore celebre.” It is the distinction, to
> use that author’s phrases, between that which a term nominat – its
> logical breadth – and that which it significat – its logical depth. In
> the case of a proposition, it is the distinction between that which
> its subject denotes and that which its predicate asserts. In the case
> of an argument, it is the distinction between the state of things in
> which its premisses are true and the state of things which is defined
> by the truth of its conclusion.

Can someone expand on what John of Salisbury wrote about the concepts of logical depth and breadth?